# Как вывести только два знака после запятой?

Tags: java

Ребят всем привет. Есть число `double res`, допустим, `0.1321231;`. Как вывести только `0.13`?

Знаю, что можно вывести так:

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", res);
```

но только что это значит? Как можно вывести стандартно через `System.out.println`?

Comment: Учитесь пользоваться документацией. Смотрим на тип `System.out`, выясняем, что это `PrintWriter`, смотрим документацию к методу `printf`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29

Здесь узнаем, что параметр `format` подробно описывается по ссылке все из той же документации: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Answer (score 9, accepted):

printf подразумевает форматирование строки в дополнение к выводу, только и всего. Для получения форматированной строки без вывода надо использовать String.format().

```
String formattedDouble = String.format("%.2f", 0.1321231);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Answer (score 17):

Чуть правильнее и быстрее будет использовать [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

```
String formattedDouble = new DecimalFormat("#0.00").format(0.1321231);
```

Само собой, строку формата `"#0.00"` стоит вынести куда-нибудь в константу, возможно, общую на все приложение.

Целиком вытаскивать объект `new DecimalFormat("#0.00")` в константу, напротив не стоит из соображений потокобезопасности.

Выигрыш в производительности по сравнению со `String.format()` может быть что-то около 2х раз. Плюс `DecimalFormat` использует настройки локали для разделителя целой и дробной частей.

Answer (score 2):

```
String formattedDouble = new DecimalFormat("#0.00").format(0.1321231);
```

Вот этот способ отлично оставляет две цифры после запятой.

Answer (score 1):

Если java не поддерживает `DecimalFormat`, то придется так:

```
Float value = 0.123f;
String result = String.format("%8.2f", value).replace(',', '.');
```