# Double - показать все цифры после точки

Tags: java, android, android-textview

Есть число 75.4500000, которое получаю при помощи `LocationManager`(GPS координаты). `LocationManager` получает координаты и преобразовывает данное значение в 75.45, т.е. обрезает нули, а нужно получать точную цифру.

Как сделать так, чтобы оно не обрезалось, а показывалось полностью?

Comment: Дак это ведь особенность хранения вещественных чисел в виде мантисы и порядка, да и число ведь получается точно таким какое пришло. Или вам все-таки нужно вывести в какой-нибудь поток число в именно таком виде? Если да, то тут уже с помощью модификаторов форматирования потока можно достичь такого результата.

Comment: Так при обрезании нулей число точности не теряет.

Comment: Посмотрите этот [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/389327/) про форматирование вещественных чисел. Там вывод двух знаков, 7 по аналогии сделаете. Для общей информации можете [посмотреть](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/) про реальный размер (в метрах) каждого десятичного знака в широте/долготе.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если Вы отображаете в TextView, просто используйте `String.format`:

```
textView.setText(String.format("%.7f",d));
```

d - Ваш double.

Comment: Спасибо большое!=) Пол вечера проковырялся, уже такой костыль изобрел для форматирования, просто ужас.